# actualizando foto con php y mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo un error en mi mysqli al procesar el update de una foto.

El código me deja subir la foto en la carpeta pero no actualiza la ruta en la base de datos.

Este es mi formulario:

```
<form action="actua_fotousu.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Id de foto:</font></td>
<td><input type="text" class="camp" name="idusuario" value="<?php echo $datosone['idusuario']?>" readonly="readonly" style="width:200px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Ruta:</font></td>
<td><input type="text" class="camp" name="foto" value="<?php echo $datosone['foto']?>" readonly="readonly" style="width:200px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php function generarCodigo($longitud)
 { 
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890'; 
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1; 

    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) 
        $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)
    }; 
    return $key; };?> 

    <font color="#ffffff">Enlace:</font>

    </td>
<td><input type="text" class="camp" name="enlace" value="K<?php echo generarCodigo(8);?>" readonly="readonly" style="width:200px;"></td>

</tr>

 <tr>
 <td><font color="#ffffff">Foto:</font></td>
 <td><img src="<?php echo $datosone['foto']; ?>" width="200" /></td>
  </tr>

<tr>
<td><font color="#ffffff">Selecciona la nueva foto:</font></td>
<td><input type="file" name="file_array"></td>
</tr>

</table>
<br><br>
       <td colspan="2">
<div class="inicia_sesion"><input class="md-trigger boton" type="submit" value="Guardar" id="btn_inicia"/></div>
       </td>
</form>
```

Y este es el archivo que procesa: actua_fotousu.php

```
<?php

    ModificarProducto($_POST['idusuario'], $_POST['foto'], $_POST['enlace'] );

    $idusuario=$_POST['idusuario'];
    $foto=$_POST['foto'];
    $enlace=$_POST['enlace'];

     $ruta="".$foto;
     unlink($ruta);

    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    $lugar="foto/".$enlace."_".$name_array;
    $lugar1="foto/".$enlace."_".$name_array;
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array,$lugar);



    function ModificarProducto($idusuario, $foto, $enlace, $lugar1)
    {
        include 'conexion.php';
        $sentencia="UPDATE usuarios SET 
        idusuario='".$idusuario."'
        , foto='".$lugar1."'
        WHERE idusuario='".$idusuario."' ";
        $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al actualizar datos".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }


?>
```

Me salen los siguientes errores:

Notice: Undefined variable: lugar1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulos\actua_fotousu.php on line 28

Warning: unlink(): Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulos\actua_fotousu.php on line 10

Seria de gran utilidad cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Comment: Estás haciendo las cosas al revés, llamando la función `ModificarProducto()` antes de verificar los datos introducidos, sin enviar todos los parámetros y, de hecho, sin usarlos todos dentro de la función. También quieres borrar un archivo sin haber creado la ruta adecuada.

Comment: Hola @Triby gracias por tu comentario de que forma podria arreglarlo? muchas gracias.